# Lyapunov CLT for dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $\{X_{1},\ldots ,X_{d}\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables, each with finite expected value $ E[X_{i}]$ and variance $ \operatorname{Var}[X_{i}]$. We define
$$s_{d}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{d} \operatorname{Var}[X_{i}].$$
If for some $\delta >0$, the following Lyapunov’s condition holds true
\begin{align*}
    &\lim_{d \to \infty} \frac{1}{s_{d}^{2+\delta}} \sum_{i=1}^{d} E\left[ |X_{i} - E[X_i]|^{2+\delta}\right] = 0, \qquad \text{then},\\
    &\frac{1}{s_{d}} \sum_{i=1}^{d} (X_{i} - E[X_{i}]) \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,1),  
\end{align*}
as $d$ tends to infinity. Here  $\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to}$ signifies the convergence in distribution.

Is there any similar kind of Lyapunov's result that exists for dependent random variables $\{X_1,…, X_d\}$? Any help or lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which kind of dependence is of interest for you? Would martingale differences be enough for your purpose?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: if we rearrange the sequence elements in the matrix form, the elements in the same row or the same column are dependent. Any two elements that are neither in the same row nor in the same column in a matrix rearranged form are pairwise independent.  If we check for pair-wise independence, exactly half of the pairs are dependent, and the rest half are independent.